# GDAL error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, xcode, pip, gdal

I am getting increasingly frustrated with this issue, but I have been trying to reinstall GDAL in order to install the new version of QGIS. When I try to install it using `pip install GDAL` I get the following:

```
Installing collected packages: GDAL
  Running setup.py install for GDAL
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.9/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/extensions/gdal_wrap.o
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2230:11: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]
                        res = SWIG_AddCast(res);
                        ~~~ ^              ~~~
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2233:11: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]
                        res = SWIG_AddCast(res);
                        ~~~ ^              ~~~
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3515:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALGetMetadataDomainList'
        return GDALGetMetadataDomainList( self );
               ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3753:5: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'
        CPLVirtualMem *vmem;
        ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3761:5: error: unknown type name 'GDALTileOrganization'
        GDALTileOrganization eTileOrganization;
        ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3836:15: warning: unused variable 'start_addr' [-Wunused-variable]
            char* start_addr = (char*)CPLVirtualMemGetAddr( self->vmem ) + start_offset;
                  ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4237:9: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'
            CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALDatasetGetVirtualMem( self,
            ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4237:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALDatasetGetVirtualMem'
            CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALDatasetGetVirtualMem( self,
                                  ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4263:237: error: unknown type name 'GDALTileOrganization'
    SWIGINTERN CPLVirtualMemShadow *GDALDatasetShadow_GetTiledVirtualMem(GDALDatasetShadow *self,GDALRWFlag eRWFlag,int nXOff,int nYOff,int nXSize,int nYSize,int nTileXSize,int nTileYSize,GDALDataType eBufType,int band_list,int *pband_list,GDALTileOrganization eTileOrganization,size_t nCacheSize,char **options=NULL){
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4266:9: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'
            CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALDatasetGetTiledVirtualMem( self,
            ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4620:9: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'
            CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem( self,
            ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4620:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem'
            CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem( self,
                                  ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4647:9: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'
            CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALGetVirtualMemAuto( self,
            ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4647:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALGetVirtualMemAuto'
            CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALGetVirtualMemAuto( self,
                                  ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4667:9: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'
            CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALRasterBandGetTiledVirtualMem( self,
            ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4667:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALRasterBandGetTiledVirtualMem'; did you mean 'GDALRasterBandShadow_GetVirtualMem'?
            CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALRasterBandGetTiledVirtualMem( self,
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                  GDALRasterBandShadow_GetVirtualMem
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4619:33: note: 'GDALRasterBandShadow_GetVirtualMem' declared here
    SWIGINTERN CPLVirtualMemShadow *GDALRasterBandShadow_GetVirtualMem(GDALRasterBandShadow *self,GDALRWFlag eRWFlag,int nXOff,int nYOff,int nXSize,int nYSize,int nBufXSize,int nBufYSize,GDALDataType eBufType,size_t nCacheSize,size_t nPageSizeHint,char **options=NULL){
                                    ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4685:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GTO_BSQ'
            vmemshadow->eTileOrganization = GTO_BSQ;
                                            ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4867:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALRATChangesAreWrittenToFile'
            return GDALRATChangesAreWrittenToFile( self );
                   ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:7845:31: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
            PyObject *item_list = PyMapping_Items( obj1 );
                                  ^
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:1354:50: note: expanded from macro 'PyMapping_Items'
    #define PyMapping_Items(O) PyObject_CallMethod(O,"items",NULL)
                                                     ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11385:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
          buf->format = "B";
                        ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11390:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
          buf->format = "h";
                        ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11395:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
          buf->format = "H";
                        ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11400:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
          buf->format = "i";
                        ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11405:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
          buf->format = "I";
                        ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11410:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
          buf->format = "f";
                        ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11415:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
          buf->format = "F";
                        ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11420:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
          buf->format = "B";
                        ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:13656:3: error: unknown type name 'GDALTileOrganization'
      GDALTileOrganization arg12 ;
      ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:13768:24: error: unknown type name 'GDALTileOrganization'
      arg12 = static_cast< GDALTileOrganization >(val12);
                           ^
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:23687:14: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'void *' to itself [-Wself-assign]
      clientdata = clientdata;
      ~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
    13 warnings and 17 errors generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/y2/thsw8bnj0xz0vp55gcykptfw0000gn/T/pip_build_root/GDAL/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/y2/thsw8bnj0xz0vp55gcykptfw0000gn/T/pip-bLqvAE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7

copying gdal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7

copying ogr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7

copying osr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7

copying gdalconst.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7

copying gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/gdal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/gdal_array.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/gdalconst.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/ogr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/osr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

running build_ext

building 'osgeo._gdal' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/extensions

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.9/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/extensions/gdal_wrap.o

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2230:11: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]

                    res = SWIG_AddCast(res);

                    ~~~ ^              ~~~

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2233:11: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]

                    res = SWIG_AddCast(res);

                    ~~~ ^              ~~~

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3515:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALGetMetadataDomainList'

    return GDALGetMetadataDomainList( self );

           ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3753:5: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'

    CPLVirtualMem *vmem;

    ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3761:5: error: unknown type name 'GDALTileOrganization'

    GDALTileOrganization eTileOrganization;

    ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3836:15: warning: unused variable 'start_addr' [-Wunused-variable]

        char* start_addr = (char*)CPLVirtualMemGetAddr( self->vmem ) + start_offset;

              ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4237:9: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'

        CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALDatasetGetVirtualMem( self,

        ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4237:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALDatasetGetVirtualMem'

        CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALDatasetGetVirtualMem( self,

                              ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4263:237: error: unknown type name 'GDALTileOrganization'

SWIGINTERN CPLVirtualMemShadow *GDALDatasetShadow_GetTiledVirtualMem(GDALDatasetShadow *self,GDALRWFlag eRWFlag,int nXOff,int nYOff,int nXSize,int nYSize,int nTileXSize,int nTileYSize,GDALDataType eBufType,int band_list,int *pband_list,GDALTileOrganization eTileOrganization,size_t nCacheSize,char **options=NULL){

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4266:9: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'

        CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALDatasetGetTiledVirtualMem( self,

        ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4620:9: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'

        CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem( self,

        ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4620:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem'

        CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem( self,

                              ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4647:9: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'

        CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALGetVirtualMemAuto( self,

        ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4647:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALGetVirtualMemAuto'

        CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALGetVirtualMemAuto( self,

                              ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4667:9: error: unknown type name 'CPLVirtualMem'

        CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALRasterBandGetTiledVirtualMem( self,

        ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4667:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALRasterBandGetTiledVirtualMem'; did you mean 'GDALRasterBandShadow_GetVirtualMem'?

        CPLVirtualMem* vmem = GDALRasterBandGetTiledVirtualMem( self,

                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                              GDALRasterBandShadow_GetVirtualMem

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4619:33: note: 'GDALRasterBandShadow_GetVirtualMem' declared here

SWIGINTERN CPLVirtualMemShadow *GDALRasterBandShadow_GetVirtualMem(GDALRasterBandShadow *self,GDALRWFlag eRWFlag,int nXOff,int nYOff,int nXSize,int nYSize,int nBufXSize,int nBufYSize,GDALDataType eBufType,size_t nCacheSize,size_t nPageSizeHint,char **options=NULL){

                                ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4685:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GTO_BSQ'

        vmemshadow->eTileOrganization = GTO_BSQ;

                                        ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4867:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALRATChangesAreWrittenToFile'

        return GDALRATChangesAreWrittenToFile( self );

               ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:7845:31: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]

        PyObject *item_list = PyMapping_Items( obj1 );

                              ^

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:1354:50: note: expanded from macro 'PyMapping_Items'

#define PyMapping_Items(O) PyObject_CallMethod(O,"items",NULL)

                                                 ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11385:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]

      buf->format = "B";

                    ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11390:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]

      buf->format = "h";

                    ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11395:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]

      buf->format = "H";

                    ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11400:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]

      buf->format = "i";

                    ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11405:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]

      buf->format = "I";

                    ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11410:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]

      buf->format = "f";

                    ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11415:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]

      buf->format = "F";

                    ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:11420:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]

      buf->format = "B";

                    ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:13656:3: error: unknown type name 'GDALTileOrganization'

  GDALTileOrganization arg12 ;

  ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:13768:24: error: unknown type name 'GDALTileOrganization'

  arg12 = static_cast< GDALTileOrganization >(val12);

                       ^

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:23687:14: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'void *' to itself [-Wself-assign]

  clientdata = clientdata;

  ~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~

13 warnings and 17 errors generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

The main point being the last line: error: `command 'cc' failed with exit status`. I have tried virtually every fix I found on Stackoverflow and everywhere else, from the export CFLAG strategy to deleting files. I still get that error.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: Did you install gdal? Did you install the development version, libgdal-dev, to have the header files as well for compilation?

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.3 Mavericks. Do I pip install libgdal-dev? I tried it now and got this: Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement gdal-dev

Comment: libgdal-dev is not a Python package. You'll have to install it manually, or use an OSX package manager like homebrew, macports or fink.

Comment: The funny thing is that I have GDAL 1.11 on Homebrew but I can't seem to install it on PIP. I tried installing libgdal-dev using brew but I got this error: No available formula for libgdal-dev

Comment: Sorry, libgdal-dev is the typical linux package name. If you installed GDAL through brew, you may ok.

Comment: Perhaps (likely) pip isn't picking up the GDAL include headers. Check if you have GDAL related include headers file in `/usr/local/include`, and the GDAL library in `/usr/local/lib`. If so, you'll probably need to tell `pip` to look there for the header files and library.

Comment: Any chance, btw, you can try to install `pygdal` instead? I don't know if it has the same functionality, but perhaps it does a better job (or produce a clearer error).

Comment: I can't find those file: the header and the GDAL library. How do I get them on Mac?

Comment: If you can't find them (`find /usr/local -name gdal.h`), then things may have gone wrong when installing gdal itself. I've used `brew install gdal` (possibly you'll need `--force` or `--rewrite` if you try this again); that should put `gdal.h` in `/usr/local/include`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55193/discussion-between-evert-and-siya).

Comment: Mmm, ok well I used easy_install and GDAL 1.11 installed. I can find the headers. But for some reason QGIS still says it needs GDAL 1.11 to be installed when it's there.

Comment: That sounds like a different issue; the current question is about the GDAL python bindings, which apparently are installed now (can you do `>>> import gdal`?).

Comment: I get this error when I run that command: ImportError: No module named gdal

Answer (score 13):

I've just run into this (hence finding your question). I solved it by making sure that the version of (Python's) `GDAL` I was trying to install matched that of the `libgdal` on the system.

In my case pip was pulling in `GDAL==1.11.0`, whereas the version of `libgdal` I had was `1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1`. Running `pip install GDAL==1.10.0` (maybe with the actual version substituted) should do the right thing.

Your compiler error is `GDAL 1.11.0` expecting symbols that are only there in the most recent version of `libgdal`.